# Primefaces commandButton inside dataTable action

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 5.0, 
I have a dataTable, with a button at the last column, 
I want a certain method in the bean to be executed according to the row where the button is, and i pass 2 values of that row to do that, 
so i have this code:

```
<p:dataTable var="sim" id="idSimTable" value="#{searchSimulationLog.simulations}"  
                         emptyMessage="Il y a aucun simulation avec ce critaire"
                         widgetVar="simTable"
                         filteredValue="#{searchSimulationLog.filtredSimulations}"
                         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                         paginator="true" rows="10"
                         selection="#{searchSimulationLog.selectedSimulation}">  
.
.
.
    <p:column headerText="Visualiser" width="80">
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <p:commandButton action="#{searchSimulationLog.generateContratById(sim.simId, sim.productCode)}" value="(#{sim.simId}, #{sim.productCode})" />
         </div>
    </p:column>
```

and the bean just have some normal getters/setters
so far everything seems nice and works like a charm, 
until i filter!
when i filter let's say with the id(so there is only one row in the dataTable) and i press the button, i always get the first values(before filtering) passed to the method(simId and productCode) 
ironically the `value` property of the commandButton gets right values .. but wrong ones are passing.

What's wrong here!

Comment: Please share some code of the bean which is supplying the collection and the scope of it please. My first guess is that your bean is supplying a changed collection after the commandbutton has been submitted to the server.

Comment: put more code, what is sim, var tag in datatable???